# Can I have a valid mail server without buying a certificate?

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, imap

I'm mounting my own mail server and I really get it working now (telnet), I just need to configure IMAP to finish.

BUT three things:

1. I used telnet to send email to gmail. OK! but the mail arrived says: **Gmail can't verify that example.com actually sent this message.**
2. I used gmail to send email to my mail server. OK! (Emails arrived fine, I go to `/var/spool/mail/virtual/(mailbox) --> nano *filename*`)
3. I cannot connect to the account (for example myaccount@example.com) in Roundcube, I go to the logs and there's an error on imap:  **dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: Can't load ssl_cert: There is no valid PEM certificate. (You probably forgot '<' from ssl_cert=<)**

During the configuration of the mail server I have seen some parameters related to SSL and certificates, but that's my question:

Is necessary to buy a SSL certificate, can I configure it with self-signed certificates? Can I avoid SSL over IMAP?

Thanks.

Comment: Running IMAP (or anything authenticated) without SSL is a really really bad idea.  You can use self-signed certificates if you're handy, and don't mind the pain of getting untrusted certs working with your email clients.  You could use letsencrypt, but also requires some setup and know how.

Comment: @Max I will abort this operation of mounting my own Mail Server, I don't have time. I will go with Amazon SES. Bye and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buying SSL is not necessary, you need valid domain and SPF record, like

```
v=spf1 include:example.com ~all
```

learn more [here](https://www.zoho.com/campaigns/help/setup-spf-dkim.html)

Comment: Hey I have another question, I'm using Amazon SES to mount my mail server, it is necessary?